# iPhone (hardware?) id for instruments launched from shell

Tags: iphone, macos, shell, instruments

Hey.
I'm trying to launch Instruments from shell with iPhone specified as target. As for [this apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html) I should be able to specify target with '-w' parameter but I don't know what should be there.

I've tried iPhone name, I've tried its UUID but nothing worked - constantly I get 'Unknown hardware device specified'. I also checked content of some saved trace document, but inside I see UUID of the iPhone. Maybe it is some prefix/suffix that should be added to the UUID ?

In the end i would like to get the following working:

```
instruments -t /Users/user/Template.tracetemplate -D /Users/user/res.trace -w iPhoneID AppName
```

Comment: My assumption is that non-gui version of instruments never really worked this way. Additionally when launching instruments from command line it displays version 1.0 while, my gui version is 3.0 - I assume Apple abandoned non-gui version and has no intention of making it work. Check related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/i-os4-ui-automation-can-it-be-launched-from-terminal-or-through-apple-script

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me(taken from http://lemonjar.com/blog/?p=69):

`instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate <full_path_to_application> -e UIASCRIPT <path_to_script.js> -e UIARESULTSPATH <output_results_path>`

There a few important things to note though:

1. the -w parameter is not required unless you want to run the scripts on your device. If you want to run your scripts on the simulator, simply omit this parameter from the command.
2. full_path_to_application is the path to your .app file that is created by your simulator. For me, the path was

   > /Users/fwasim/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/AA6BA2E1-D505-4864-BECC-29ADEE28194D/name_of_application.app

   this path might be different for anyone else depending on what iOS version are you running on your simulator. Also remember to put this path in double quotation marks.
3. The path_to_script.js should be the FULL PATH to where your automation script written in javascript is saved. Also remember to put this path in double quotation marks.
4. Lastly output results path is the path where you want to save the output results. Also remember to put this path in double quotation marks.

These were the points I had been missing on and thus was getting some of the errors mentioned above.

Comment: Btw, I was trying to run on the simulator, not the device.

Answer (score 0):

The hex "Identifier" value you find in the Organizer in the device's general information pane  should work.

Comment: any idea on getting it to run on the simulator?