# Can Instruments be used using the command line?

Tags: c, xcode, instruments

Can Instruments be used as a replacement for

> valgrind

If one wants to check for memory leaks using instruments can it be used from the terminal?

Comment: I'm also interested in the XCode 13 answer to this same question.  We basically want to supervise a program run to get data like the cpu cycles used in the execution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instruments has a command line interface:

```
$ instruments -h
```

Example usage:

```
$ instruments -t mytemplate -a myapp.app
```

For leaks, try the `Leaks.tracetemplate`. To see all available templates, use `-s`.

There is another executable, just called `leaks`. You can inspect any running application by giving `leaks` its PID:

```
$ echo $$
620

$ leaks 620
leaks Report Version:  2.0 
Process:         bash [620]
Path:            /bin/bash
Load Address:    0x100000000
...
Process 620: 37983 nodes malloced for 1123 KB
Process 620: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.
```

Read more about leaks in the Apple developer [reference library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH5-SW22).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to launch or attach UIAutomation tool to a process on the actual iOS device using Instruments command line interface ?

Comment: instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate <full_path_to_application> -e UIASCRIPT <script.js> -e UIARESULTSPATH <output_results_path>

Found on http://lemonjar.com/blog/?p=69

Comment: -a options no longer exists.

instruments, version 9.0 (63198)
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 9, if you want to profile a iOS app, an example command like this:

```
instruments -t Zombies -w 'iPhone SE (11.0.1) [XXX] (Simulator)' MyApp.app
```

instruments command ref:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Recording,Pausing,andStoppingTraces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH12-SW3