# How to run UIAutomation script from command line to Simulator

Tags: iphone, command-line, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I have automated my iOS application using UIAutomation, To run this I launch iOS Instruments and run the script. If Same automation script I want to run to the device I use the below command which works as desired

instruments -w  -t  /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate myapp -e UIASCRIPT regression.js

But how do I run this from the command line to iOS Simulator ?

Please suggest.

Thanks
Sougata

Comment: Where do you keep this regression.js and any good tutorial for learning to write script's for automation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't supply the '-w' argument and build your app for the simulator sdk it should launch on the simulator.

Comment: That time I get the below error, instruments[25317:60f] Argument 'UIASCRIPT' does not point to a valid script. Using script defined in template.
Thu Nov 10 10:01:25 shopablejob-lx instruments[25317] <Error>: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetCurrentCursorLocation: Invalid connection

Comment: one thing if I use a simple js, it launch the iPad simulator but throws below exception   Thu Nov 10 14:48:17 shopablejob-lx instruments[26766] <Error>: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetCurrentCursorLocation: Invalid connection
Thu Nov 10 14:48:17 shopablejob-lx instruments[26766] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
2011-11-10 14:48:17.976 instruments[26766:60f] Recording cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.

Comment: Does this script work if you run it via the Instruments app (not command line)?  I think you need to use "myapp.app" which should be a path to your built application.  I have a script which builds my app to a specific folder and then I use the path the the .app folder.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 6.0.1**, running with the `-w` switch and passing in the symbolic name of the simulator [appears to now be required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) (at least that's the only way I got it to work, and I've had others verify and point me to this solution).

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line/25953862#25953862) from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) that has an explicit example.

You can also find a [bash shell script](http://sohail.io/2014/09/20/xcode-6-and-running-uiautomation-test-from-the-command-line/) that will handle invocation for you, automating the resolution of UDID and GUIDs in your simulator app paths.