# How to play recorded scripts in UIAutomation?

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to work with UIAutomation, and here's a problem. I'm starting to record some actions with my app (like in FoneMonkey).Recording stops when I press the Record button, but how can I replay it?

Answer (score 0):

Playing a script is done by either clicking the play button found below the script editor or by clicking Instruments Record button found in the upper-left of the trace window. In either case, you'll have to have set your target appropriately under the Choose Target popup.

You can also play back scripts via the command line instruments tool. See [Can the UI Automation instrument be run from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) from more details.