# Launching Instruments.app from the command line or in any otherwise automated fashion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments

i'm wondering if there is any information out there on runinng the Instruments application from the command line, or otherwise launct the app in some automated fashion externally.

I'm aware of the "instruments" command line tool, but that seems to run Instruments/DTrace silently and collects info into a log file — that's not what i want to do. I would like to emulate — essentially — what Xcode does when you press the profile button. Launch the instruments GUI and have it, say, attach to a given given Process ID, so that the user sitting in front of the Mac can then interact with the app, see the data it collects etc.

Xcode does it, so surely there must be some kind of API?

thanx,
marc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line

Comment: sorry, but did you read my question beyond the first line? i'm aware of the "instruments" command line tool. i want to launch the Instruments *application* and have it run on a given process.