# Instruments: Can I run an iOS App using Instruments command line mode?

Tags: ios, testing, instruments

I read from this question:
[Can the UI Automation instrument be run from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line?lq=1)

that we can test simulator builds with instruments command line. But I cannot find info about whether or not this would work on a real device too.

The command line seems to need an argument of the full path to the app on device. Is it also used for real devices? If so, how can I get the path.

Or if anyone has a more detailed description about how to work with a real device, it'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is OK to just give the local (Mac) IPA path, but make sure the -w [device identifier] parameter is correct. instruments will then try to find the app on the device and run it.