# ios how to launch app on device using command line

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am doing ci stuff now. Everything works well, I can package and install ipa on device.
But I don't know how to launch the app. I search Google million times to see whether there is 
some methods to do it. Unfortunately, I can't solve the problem now.
   Any points. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Million times Google` Great Effort.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools available for this now. Your mileage may vary.

- https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
- https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice
- https://github.com/robovm/robovm

You can also try using the [Instruments command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) for launching apps (for example, if you need to run UI Automation).

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron points out RoboVM can do this using its wrappers around libimobiledevice. These can be used standalone. Just download the latest jar file from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-libimobiledevice/0.0.7/ and call it like this:

```
java -cp robovm-libimobiledevice-0.0.7.jar org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher
```

This will print out some help on how to use this tool.

Answer (score -5):

Plug in your iOS device, put it in provisioning portal, click run on Xcode. Make sure your device is displayed on the right of the run button.

Xcode 5 should enable you to do this all from the app.