# views, methods and function of ios device from bash

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash

I'm doing a research for my thesis and I would like to know how I can access to the views  methods or functions of the user interface(like Android View Client for Android devices) of a ios device from bash without touching the device connected. The reason is that I want to create a self-test for an app and then I would do things like touches or gestures via software. How could i do? Can you give me some guidelines? 
must work for devices without jailbreak
Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

This is not practical / possible. Instead, you should look into [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html). You can use javascript to simulate all interactions with an app on either actual hardware or in the simulator.

Comment: I would use the terminal. other possibilities?

Comment: Yes, you can run the javascript UIAutomation script from the command line if you like. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line).