# Add UI Automation tests to continuous integration server with Xcode service

Tags: xcode, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have a problem when I want to include automation tests to my Xcode bot.

- First, I have created in Instruments a template in order to execute UI Automation tests. In this template, there is a simple script that tests button's position in my iPad application.
- I have successfully added this in my Xcode project, in the shared scheme. (Edited scheme, then went to profile section, added instrument from my template folder.)
- From Xcode, I launch a **Product › Profile** command, and everything is OK.

Then after committing this scheme, I supposed, I could see something on my server through the Xcode service web interface. But I can't  see anything related to profiling and my automation tests. My unit test runs fine but not my automation test, I've got no log for it.

Comment: Apple doesn't support UI Automation very well... Even calling it from command line is hard. Not speaking about parsing the result plist, which is undocumented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, have you got some documentations, even if it's not easy to use ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line

Comment: You might also look at the Bwoken project on github: https://github.com/bendyworks/bwoken

Comment: ok thank you. I wanted to mark it as answered but not enough reputation