# Running Automation script without running Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I have written a UI automation script in Instruments and Its working perfectly. Now I want to know is there any way that I simply double click on script and Its start working or at least I don't need to run Xcode for running the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the UI Automation instrument be run from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instruments -w 1.device_id -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate 2.application -e UIASCRIPT 3.script -e UI-ARESULTSPATH 4.results path
```

The ones marked with 1. 2. 3. 4. are the variables that you type. Use this code, put in your device id, app, script and result path and run the whole line in Terminal

Comment: for this i need to build the project. lets say i have only ".ipa" file  and script can i run script?

Comment: Yes you can run the script. At 2.applicatian you can specify the path to the application or command to launch it.