# Having an issue Running instruments using terminal

Tags: ios, automated-tests, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have used this below command to run automation template using instruments.

**instruments -t /Applications/xcode5.0.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1/Applications/93F12976-0667-4180-904A-95ECA172C78C/myapp.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/myUserName/Desktop/TestScript.js**

This command is able to open the simulator and my app in the simulator but, its not running the TestScript.js file, because when this file is loaded into instruments its adding up escape sequences in my code, which is ruining my code and not allowing to run the script.

did anybody face this issue before?

Or any body has any suggestion on running instruments using terminal.

Comment: [See this answer maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) I'm just starting the research for my own project and this is what I came across.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Braains. I actually solved this issue. the problem was with conversion of txt file into java script file. I was using rich text format in text edit, which was inserting escape sequences into the js file.