# WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread in UI Automation

Tags: javascript, ios-ui-automation

When I tried to run my automation scripts through the terminal with Xcode 6 I got this error message:

```
WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
```

Can someone help me to run the automation scripts through terminal or instrument in Xcode 6.

Comment: I was also having this issue while testing with Appium. I thought it was a blocking issues for my tests, but it wasn't. I started using Appium's ios_webkit_proxy_launcher.js to test against Safari on iOS and even though I still get this error on the logs, it doesn't block the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same message infrequently -- even when things run successfully.

You may be having troubles running instruments from command line because of changes to command line utilities for XCode 6.

Check out [UIAutomation test invocation from the command line with Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892427/uiautomation-test-invocation-from-the-command-line-with-xcode-6)

adding the -w flag made things work again for me. i.e.

```
-w "Resizable iPad (8.0 Simulator)"
```

Also, make sure you're passing the -w before the path to the app file:

```
instruments -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" -w "iPad Air (8.0 Simulator)" "/path/to/My.app" -e UIASCRIPT "scriptola.js"
```

Here's a list of devices:

- Resizable iPad (8.0 Simulator)
- Resizable iPhone (8.0 Simulator)
- iPad 2 (7.1 Simulator)
- iPad 2 (8.0 Simulator)
- iPad Air (7.1 Simulator)
- iPad Air (8.0 Simulator)
- iPad Retina (7.1 Simulator)
- iPad Retina (8.0 Simulator)
- iPhone 4s (7.1 Simulator)
- iPhone 4s (8.0 Simulator)
- iPhone 5 (7.1 Simulator)
- iPhone 5 (8.0 Simulator)
- iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator)
- iPhone 5s (8.0 Simulator)
- iPhone 6 (8.0 Simulator)
- iPhone 6 Plus (8.0 Simulator)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , I resolved it by following steps :

Check ur UIAutomation is enabled or not in the device ?
-> To check it , Go to settings -> Developer -> Enable UIAutomation

restart your device , and then again try.
It works for me ... :)