# UIAutomation - WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread

Tags: webkit, instruments, ui-automation

Running UIAutomation from the command line I often get:

```
WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
```

Note, I'm using the `-w` flag and it's at the beginning. This answer didn't help: [WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread in UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919234/r-webkit-threading-violation-initial-use-of-webkit-from-a-secondary-thread-in)

Any idea how to avoid?

==== UPDATE

Just getting Instruments NOT to print this out would be useful.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are launching app which is developer certificate signed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread in UI Automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919234/webkit-threading-violation-initial-use-of-webkit-from-a-secondary-thread-in-ui)