# How to run xcode UI Automation tests using command line

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to integrate UI Automation scripts with `Jenkins`.
Can you please tell, how to run UI Automation Scripts using command line on specific devices. I am using `XCode 8`.

Comment: Try adding an "Execute shell" build step to your project and refer to this answer: [Can the UI Automation instrument be run from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) about running tests from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Huhu,

the UI Automation isn't longer support in Xcode 8. See this post: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48936

You have to update to XCode-ui-testing.

if you work with Xcode 7, try this:

- give the complete path to the app with the .app extension,
- Put the DeviceID
  and the script into "",
- try it with the device name, if it doesn't work.

Here a sample that works for me.

```
instruments -w "DeviceID" -t PATHTOTEMPLATE/Automation.tracetemplate PATHTOAPP/ConsumeriOS.app -e UIASCRIPT "PATHTOSCRIPT/UITest.js"
```